# getting an error in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am getting an error in the following code. I could not guess what mistake i have done for such error to come up.

remote.h

```
 struct RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG  //Message Data
 {
  int  uDeviceID;
  int  uProtocolVersion;
  int  uReserved[5];
 };
```

RS232MsgRequestSession.m

```
@implementation RS232MsgRequestSession

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        struct RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG st;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

xyz.h

```
#import "RS232MsgRequestSession.h"

@implementation xyz

     -(void)Open{

         RS232MsgRequestSession* pMsg = [[RS232MsgRequestSession alloc]init];

    pMsg->st.uProtocolVersion = RS232_VERSION; //error
    pMsg->st.uDeviceID = RS232_PROTOCOL_DEVICE_ID; //error
    memset(pMsg->st.uReserved,0x00,sizeof(pMsg->st.uReserved)); //error

    }
@end
```

Error:'struct RS232MsgRequestSession' has no member named 'st'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put iVar declaration in class's @interface block. In your code st is just a local variable in init method:

```
@interface RS232MsgRequestSession : NSObject{
...
@public
struct RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG st;
}
...
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

What you forgot to do was include the `struct` in your `@interface` as a public instance variable:

```
@interface RMH2532MsgRequestSession : NSObject {
@public
   struct RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG st;
}
- (void) Open;
@end
```

And your `@implementation` should be empty:

```
@implementation RS232MsgRequestSession
@end
```

PS - The reason why you must use `@public` here is because in `xyz`, you were doing a direct dereference of the object using the member operator `->`. This is not allowed by default when working with Objective-C objects. However, if the instance variables are under a `@public` attribute, then you will not have any problems doing this.

As you might have guessed by now, using `@public` is a **Very Bad Idea** -- usually. It breaks encapsulation and opens a pandora's box of potential problems that you wouldn't have otherwise had if you had used proper encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining st as a local variable in the init function.

Move `struct RMH_REQUEST_SESSION_MSG st;` to the class definition in RS232MsgRequestSession.h